# How to run silverlight tests in visual studio 2015 with Resharper 10

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2015, resharper

We upgraded our solution from VS 2010 and Resharper 7 to Vs 2015 and Resharper 10, but the silverlight Tests is not supported anymore. What to do?

Comment: I am getting the same issue, any news here?

Comment: Hi Rolando, 
sorry, did not find a solution, so I have old VS running to do the tests.

Comment: hi, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185415/resharper-is-not-runing-tests-with-attribute-test