# Resharper is not runing tests with attribute [Test]

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I am running the latest version of Resharper 2016.2 and Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and today when I wanted create and run new tests on my solution the context menus to run the tests don't appear. I tried to restoring the default setting for VS 2015 and reinstalling resharper and still can't see this context menu.. any solution? 
BTW: The project where unit test are located is of type silverlight project.

[image: the Image shows that i am not able to run the tests]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReSharper doesn't support running Silverlight tests, which need to be run in a Silverlight process, and ReSharper only ships with a .net framework test runner host.

Comment: thank you. I will add more info from resharper support:" Out-of-the-box ReSharper does not support running Unit Tests in Silverlight projects. There were a plugin for ReSharper which helped running such tests AgUnit http://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/AgUnit/, but as I may see it has not been updated for a long time and the latest version supports R# 8.x build only."